# Set value of input field to whatever is clicked

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have this feature where I want to have something that essentially functions the same as what's on http://www.iconfinder.com/

Notice how when you begin to enter something into the search bar, a list of suggestion appears. Whenever you click on one of them, the value of the  changes to whatever is clicked on.

My approach to this problem is by using some jQuery code that is as follows:

```
$("h1#poli").click(function putIn_one(){
            var htmlStr_one = $(this).html();
            var seed_one_one = $('input#seed_one').val();   

            htmlStr_one = seed_one_one;
        });
```

I already have code that correctly functions so that when someone enters something into the input field, a list of suggestions appears.  will appear for every possible suggestion. What I need to do is find out how to make it so that when the  is clicked on, the value of the input field is dynamically changed.

Any ideas?

Thanks,

Lance

Comment: Have you looked at JQuery UI's Autocomplete?  It already has the functionality you are looking for...

Comment: Since you're using jQuery already, why don't you use jQuery autocomplete?

Answer (score 0):

You should do `$('input#seed_one').val(htmlStr_one);` instead of `htmlStr_one = seed_one_one;`. Also use live if you are dynamically fetching the results.

```
$("h1#poli").live('click', function putIn_one() {
    var htmlStr_one = $(this).text();
    $('input#seed_one').val(htmlStr_one);
});
```